# What is the name of a web comic strip that makes a joke of Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

A few years ago I read a comic strip that makes a joke about what does AI studies. In the last square the character says something like its goal is to make Skynet. Does anybody know its name?

Comment: That sounds like an [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/). Just doing a quick search for xkcd skynet I found this: https://xkcd.com/1046/ I'm sure there are tons of other xkcd where they poke fun at AI.

Comment: Tonight on Jeopardy, Wilson! And tonight's categories are decimal places of PI, and Are You Sarah Conner?

Answer (score -1):

The [S.S.D.D. webcomic](http://www.poisonedminds.com/) has filler strips about AIs and their history. There have been several strips written as if the commentator was a lecturer in AI studies. Sadly, there is no search facility on the site, so I can't find any examples.